# Efficient way to parse this string into array in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

**Background**

I have an array which I create by splitting a string based on every occurrence of `0d0a` using `preg_split('/(?<=0d0a)(?!$)/')`.

For example:

```
$string = "78781110d0a78782220d0a";
```

will be split into:

```
Array ( [0] => 78781110d0a [1] => 78782220d0a )
```

A valid array element has to start with `7878` and end with `0d0a`.

**The Problem**

But sometimes, there's an additional `0d0a` in the string which splits into an extra and invalid array element, i.e., that doesn't begin with `7878`.

Take this string for example:

```
$string = "78781110d0a2220d0a78783330d0a";
```

This is split into:

```
Array ( [0] => 78781110d0a [1] => 2220d0a [2] => 78783330d0a )
```

But it should actually be:

```
Array ( [0] => 78781110d0a2220d0a [1] => 78783330d0a)
```

**My Solution**

I've written the following (messy) code to get around this:

```
    $data = Array('78781110d0a','2220d0a','78783330d0a');
    $i = 0; //count for $data array;
    $j = 0; //count for $dataFixed array;
    $dataFixed = $data;

    foreach($data as $packet) {
        if (substr($packet,0,4) != "7878") { //if packet doesn't start with 7878, do some fixing
            if ($i != 0) { //its the first packet, can't help it!
                $j++;                    

                if ((substr(strtolower($packet), -4, 4) == "0d0a")) { //if the packet doesn't end with 0d0a, its 'mostly' not valid, so discard it
                    $dataFixed[$i-$j] = $dataFixed[$i-$j] . $packet;
                }
                    unset($dataFixed[$i-$j+1]);                        
                    $dataFixed = array_values($dataFixed);
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

**Description**

I first copy the array to another array `$dataFixed`. In a `foreach` loop of the `$data` array, I check whether it starts with `7878`. If it doesn't, I join it with the previous array in `$data`. I then unset the current array in `$dataFixed` and reset the array elements with `array_values`.

But I'm not very confident about this solution.. Is there a better, more efficient way?

**UPDATE**

What if the input string doesn't end in `0d0a` like its supposed to? It will stick to the previous array element..

For e.g.: in the string `78781110d0a2220d0a78783330d0a0000`, `0000` should be separated as another array element.

Comment: Do these strings have a definitive end? Why don't you latch onto the end of the string: preg_split('/7878([0-9][a-zA-Z])*0d0a$') where $ is the end of the string. This will force 0d0a to be at the end of the line. If you have a long string with no end of line marker then you have a problem as there's no way to tell regex which 0d0a is the RIGHT one to match. In that case, you need to look into regex greed.

Comment: @Reddox curious if my answer has worked for you, or if you can provide a full data set to test further. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use another [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=7878)` to form:

```
preg_split('/(?<=0d0a)(?=7878)/',$string)
```

*Note: I removed `(?!$)` because I wasn't sure what that was for, based on your example data.*

For example, this code:

```php
$string = "78781110d0a2220d0a78783330d0a";
$array  = preg_split('/(?<=0d0a)(?=7878)(?!$)/',$string);
print_r($array);
```

Results in:

`Array ( [0] => 78781110d0a2220d0a [1] => 78783330d0a )`

**UPDATE:**

Based on your revised question of having possible random characters at the end of the input string, you can add three lines to make a complete program of:

```php
$string = "78781110d0a2220d0a787830d0a330d0a0000";
$array  = preg_split('/(?<=0d0a)(?=7878)/',$string);
$temp = preg_split('/(7878.*0d0a)/',$array[count($array)-1],null,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$array[count($array)-1] = $temp[0];
if(count($temp)>1) { $array[] = $temp[1]; }
print_r($array);
```

We basically do the initial splitting, then split the last element of the resulting array by the expected data format, keeping the delimiter using `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE`. The `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` ensures we won't get an empty array element if the input string doesn't end in random characters.

**UPDATE 2:**

Based on your comment below where it seems you're implying there might be random characters between any of the desired matches, and you want these random characters preserved, you could do this:

```php
$string = "0078781110d0a2220d0a2220d0a0000787830d0a330d0a000078781110d0a2220d0a0000787830d0a330d0a0000";
$split1 = preg_split('/(7878.*?0d0a)/',$string,null,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$result = array();
foreach($split1 as $e){
  $split2 = preg_split('/(.*0d0a)/',$e,null,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
  foreach($split2 as $el){
    // test if $el doesn't start with 7878 and ends with 0d0a
    if(strpos($el,'7878') !== 0 && substr($el,-4) == '0d0a'){
    //if(preg_match('/^(?!7878).*0d0a$/',$el) === 1){
      $result[ count($result)-1 ] = $result[ count($result)-1 ] . $el;
    } else {
      $result[] = $el;
    }
  }
}
print_r($result);
```

The strategy employed here is different than above. First we split the input string based on the delimiter that matches your desired data, using the nongreedy regex `.*?`. At this point we have some strings that contain the ending of a desired value and some garbage at the end, so we split again based on the last occurrence of "0d0a" with the greedy regex `.*0d0a`. We then append any of those resulting values that don't start with "7878" but end with "0d0a" to the previous value, as this should repair the first and second halves that got split because it contained an extra "0d0a".

I provided two methods for the innermost `if` statement, one using regular expressions. The regex one is marginally slower in my testing, so I've left that one commented out.

I might still not have your full requirements, so you'll have to let me know if it works and perhaps provided your full dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Works perfectly. I _really_ have to learn regex now!

Comment: Accepted for Quickest response, and most efficient solution. Thanks again.

Comment: @CharlieGorichanaz Why not just `explode('0d0a7878', $string)`?

Comment: @Reddox wants to keep the delimeter, not discard it.

Comment: And then `implode('0d0a,7878'...)`

Comment: Another possibility is an extra string at the end without an ending `0d0a`. E.g.: `78781110d0a2220d0a78783330d0a0000`. We need to split the 0000 into another array, otherwise it'll mess-up the 2nd element..

Comment: Alternatively, what if it starts with 00007878...0d0a? Should I just use startsWith() or substr() to sanitize the string before regex?

Comment: @Reddox Is this a real world example or what? What kind of string are you parsing?

Comment: @bozdoz: This is data I get from my GPS receiver. Its standard format is `7878...0d0a` (variable length for `...`). Sometimes, it sends messy data, like multiple packets joined together. And sometimes, because of a patchy network, we could get weird chars before and after the real packet, so `xx7878..0d0a` or `7878..0d0axxx`.

Comment: @Reddox I really think you should use preg_match_all instead.  It's really what you're looking for, and preg_split is more of a fancy solution (finding and splitting delimiters as opposed to matching the data format you're looking for).  Otherwise, try stripping the string of the extra characters before doing the split.  See how that performs.

Comment: @bozdoz: I'm inclined to agree with you about `preg_match_all`. However, with a string like `78781110d0a2220d0a00` (with two trailing nonsense characters), your `preg_match_all` suggestion breaks. It appears to handle leading zeros well. Or with a string like `0078781110d0a2220d0a00787800d0a`, it doesn't break it off into 2 arrays.

Comment: I added the condition to my regex to ignore trailing characters: `/7878.*?0d0a(?=7878|[^(7878)]*?$)/`.  See my answer.

Comment: Sorry @CharlieGorichanaz, have had to reconsider bozdoz's solution as your preg_split doesn't handle the scenarios listed above..

Comment: @ Reddox I added a section to my answer to address your possible extra characters at the end of the input string. I think you will find this adds a negligible amount of time, keeping this answer the most efficient, and hopefully earning me the answer again. :P If you change the requirements some more, though, you'll want to use @bozdoz's answer. ^_^

Comment: @CharlieGorichanaz,appreciate your patience! But..it doesn't work on `0078781110d0a2220d0a00787800d0a00` or `78781110d0a2220d0a0000787830d0a330d0a0000`

Comment: @reddox So it seems the requirements changed again. I didn't know by the question that there could be garbage anywhere in the input string between the desired values, as the question says the **input string** might end in garbage. Do you currently not have a working solution then? Please see my second update in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead?  You can avoid all of the non-capturing groups (the look aheads, look behinds) in order to split the string (which without the non-capturing groups removes the matches), and just find the matches you're looking for:

### Updated

```
<?php
$string = "00787817878110d0a22278780d0a78783330d0a00";
preg_match_all('/7878.*?0d0a(?=7878|[^(7878)]*?$)/', $string, $arr);
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Gives an array `$arr[0] => ( [0] => 787817878110d0a22278780d0a, [1] => 78783330d0a )`.  Strips leading and trailing garbage characters (whatever doesn't start with `7878` or end with `7878` or `0d0a`.

So $arr[0] would be the array of values that you are looking for.

See example on [ideone](http://ideone.com/SPdR2t)

Works with multiple `7878` values and multiple `0d0a` values (even though that's ridiculous).

### Update

If splitting is more your style, why not avoid regular expressions altogether?

```
<?php
$string = "787817878110d0a22278780d0a78783330d0a";
$arr = explode('0d0a7878', $string);
$string = implode('0d0a,7878', $arr);
$arr = explode(',', $string);
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Here we split the string by the delimiter `0d0a7878`, which is what @CharlieGorichanaz's solution is doing, and props to him for the quick, accurate solution.  We then add a comma, because who doesn't love comma separated values? And we [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) again on the commas for an array of desired values.  Performance-wise, this ought to be faster than using regular expressions.  See [example](http://ideone.com/1NLXF4).

Comment: @dreamCoder Ah.  Doesn't seem to make sense to me... but okay. :)

Comment: I mean first result should be `78781110d0a2220d0a`

Comment: I have dropped the `?` to make it greedy, and changed `.` to `[^(7878)]` so that it will match the `2220` as requested. @dreamCoder

Comment: The values must start with 7878 but it doesn't say they won't ever contain 7878.

Comment: @CharlieGorichanaz Then I agree with Pramod's answer

Comment: @CharlieGorichanaz You gave a working answer, and I +1'd you for it.  I still think it's ridiculous to be using preg_split with so many non-capturing groups.  It's regex acrobatics, and there's probably a better solution to OP's real problem that is not apparent in the example.  I've updated my answer again (just because in principle, I think he's looking for matches, not delimiters).

Comment: bozdoz: In terms of efficiency, how would yours rank up against @CharlieGorichanaz 's preg_match()?

Comment: @Reddox Not sure.  Your example string is parsed by both scripts at .01s on ideone.com at least.  You'd have to research some benchmarking.

Comment: @Reddox I would guess that the `preg_split` is faster though.

Comment: bozdoz: @CharlieGorichanaz 's is roughly 3 times faster at `0.0000160`, while `preg_match_all` averages at `0.0000470`. +1 for the idea of matches and not delimeters! I learnt something about preg_match_all today!

Comment: @reddox Try splitting without regular expressions.  See update.

Comment: bozdoz: +1 for a simplistic approach. However, benchmarks averages around `0.0000430` (probably cause of the multiple steps?) which is still slower that @CharlieGorichanaz 's preg_split.

Comment: The updated code works well except in a situation where between two 7878..0d0a bits, there's some noise char. Eg. `007878110d0noise78780d0a78783330d0a00`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using a delimiter "0d0a" which also happens to be part of a content! Its not  possible to avoid getting junk data as long as delimiter can also be part of content. Somehow delimiter must be unique.

Possible solutions.

- Change the delimited to something else that doesn't occur as part of your data ( 000000, @!.;)
- If you are definite about length of text that easy arrange item may have, use it. As per examples its not possible.

Solutions given in answers considering only sample data you have shared. If you are confidant about what will be the content of string, then these solutions given by others are pretty good to use. Otherwise these solutions wont assure you guarantee!

**Best solution**: Fix right delimiter then use regex or explode whatever you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, unfortunately, the delimeter isn't in my control! I get this data from a device and process it as best as I can..